# WSO2 VMware image - validate email address?

Tags: wso2, wso2-stratos

I'm running the WSO2 Stratos VMware image, and I have it to the point where it's running, I've got the browser open, it's at my internal deployment of WSO2, and I've created an account for myself. The problem is, the VM isn't networked to anything, so when it tells me it sent an email to my account and would I please validate it, I can't validate it because it never actually sent an email. I thought maybe there'd be a local mail server on the Linux guest, but I couldn't find one.

Am I missing something? Do I even need to validate the account? I can't seem to access any of the Stratos services, and I suspect that the account validation has something to do with that.

Comment: I should add that the reason I wasn't getting an eth0 interface is that when I downloaded the VM, I selected "I copied it", which changed the MAC address of the VM. If you select "I moved it" or manually change the MAC configuration in /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules it should work. Also, it turns out that I don't have to validate an email address for the account to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can log in as an administrator (with the default username/password: admin/admin) and activate the tenant/account you created.